# 403 Forbidden ao acessar 192.168.0.1; 127.0.0.1 acessa com sucesso

Tags: apache, windows-7, easyphp

Instalei o EasyPHP (Win7) com **Apache 2.4.25 x86** em um cartão de memória (E:), configurei com sucesso o diretório do site (E:/Meus Web Sites/) e subi o Apache.

Ao realizar acesso local no 127.0.0.1 obtenho sucesso -- são listados no navegador os arquivos do diretório corretamente -- porém tentando o acesso local via 192.168.0.104 (IP da máquina) retorna 403 Forbidden:

> **Forbidden**
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Editei o http.conf em alguns pontos, e atualmente encontra-se da seguinte forma:

```
##testei com estas 4 linhas individualmente e simultaneamente

Listen *:80
#Listen 0.0.0.0:80
#Listen 127.0.0.1:80
#Listen 192.168.0.104:80
```

(...)

```
DocumentRoot "E:/Meus Web Sites/"
<Directory "E:/Meus Web Sites/">
```

(...)

```
<Directory "E:/Program Files (x86)/EasyPHP-Devserver-17/eds-modules">
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

(...)

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    DocumentRoot "E:/Meus Web Sites/"
    ServerName 127.0.0.1
    <Directory "E:/Meus Web Sites/">
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

*Order allow,deny*, *Allow from all* e *Listen *:80* foram sugestões de resolução do problema que encontrei por aqui mesmo, mas não foram suficientes para mim.

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver: alterei

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
```

por

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

Boa sorte a todos.